# Why would I ever use my oven's 'bake' setting when it also has a 'convection bake'?

Tags: baking, convection

Whenever I bake something I use the convection bake setting of my GE range because the fan is supposed to make for more even baking. The range also has a 'bake' setting. I'm just wondering why would I ever want to use 'bake', the setting without the fan and supposedly uneven heat? Interestingly, there is a 'convection roast' setting but no corresponding 'roast' setting!